# Know when the end of data has reached in firestore collection

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Lets say there are 100 documents in a collection. I want to load only 10 items at a time. i.e I have to fetch data 10 times when i completely load all the data from the collection. I couldn't achieve this result in firestore database collection. Each time the end has reached firestore starting getting data from the first index. In this situation when all the 100 data are loaded firestore starting loading the first 10 data.

```
          _query = _query.startAfter([receivedData.elementAt((receivedData.length-1))]).limit(10);
```

as stated in firebase documentation but couldn't achieve the behaviour. I am implementation wrong approach to achieve the result? How could i achieve this behaviour in firestore while retrieving data?

Comment: check the limit and startAfter properties from firestore documentation

Comment: tried it but couldn't achieve the behaviour.
          _query = _query.startAfter([receivedData.elementAt((receivedData.length-1))]).limit(10).This was my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but Ive done the same and you should save the data youve previously retrieved in data structure. Also not sure why you are using an array for startAfter